git clone - error: RPC failed; curl 92 HTTP/2 stream 7 was not closed cleanly: PROTOCOL_ERROR (err 1)
This is a critical issue for me as I am not able to clone.
$ git clone <repo>
Cloning into '<repo-name>'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 1705, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (61/61), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (45/45), done.
error: RPC failed; curl 92 HTTP/2 stream 7 was not closed cleanly: PROTOCOL_ERROR (err 1)
error: 1282 bytes of body are still expected
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output

It doesn't seem to be network issue. I tried to:

Restart my PC
Restarted router
Changed network provider

Tried methods in this link as well:
git clone error error: RPC failed; curl 92 HTTP/2 stream 7 was not closed cleanly before end of the underlying stream

Reinstalling git resolved this issue. But the issue happened in the same version, which I reinstalled.
Installed/Error version: 2.45.1

Try running command to increase git buffer size
git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000

then git clone <repo>

I just changed connection from home wifi to hotspot of my phone and brew immediately installed
